# Google Search Appliance XSLT header modification

Tags: google-search-appliance

I want to modify the XSLT in order to change home page header of the Google Search Appliance. I am unable to see my changes. I have done the following

1. included proxyreload=1 query parameter
2. Changed the home_page_header template to include my Hello world section.

> ```
> <xsl:template name="home_page_header">
>     <input type="hidden" name="security_token" id="token">
>       <xsl:attribute name="value">
>         <xsl:value-of select="/GSP/SECURITY_TOKEN"/>
>       </xsl:attribute>
>     </input>
>     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
>       <xsl:if test="$show_logo != '0'">
>         <tr>
>           <td rowspan="3" valign="top">
>             <xsl:call-template name="logo"/>
>             <xsl:call-template name="nbsp3"/>
>           </td>
>         </tr>
>       </xsl:if>
>       <xsl:if test="$show_top_search_box != '0'">
>         <tr>
>           <td valign="middle">
>             <xsl:call-template name="search_box">
>               <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'home'"/>
>             </xsl:call-template>
>           </td>
>         </tr>
>       </xsl:if>
>     </table>
>     <table>
>         <tr>
>             <td>Hello World</td>
>         </tr>
>     </table>
> </xsl:template>
> ```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you loading the correct frontend?

Comment: Yes I am. I sorted out the issue. I searched for "Front door" in the XSLT and made the change there.